# Angular replace data from ng-repeat item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars() | filter: car.owned == true">
    <a href="" ng-click="selectCar(car)">{{ car.name }}</a>
    ...
</div>
```

On the `ng-click` directive, I'm invoking a function `selectCar()`, passing the `car` data as a parameter. Will it be possible to replace the `car` data after the `ng-repeat`? So that when I click the anchor element, the new data will be passed as parameter?

How can I do this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simpler way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for every list item. So there's a different `car` property in all those scopes. Your `selectCar()` method is defined on the parent scope though, so if you'd do something like:

```
$scope.selectCar = function(car) {
  $scope.car = newCar;
}
```

It wouldn't have any effect since you're setting the `car` property on the parent scope. One option is to modify the object that you send to `selectCar()`. Something like:

```
$scope.selectCar = function(car) {
  var newCar = ...;
  for (var key in newCar) {
    car[key] = newCar[key];
  }
}
```

But that's not a very nice way to solve it. Another option is to create a new directive that passes the `ng-repeat` scope into the event handler. Something like this:

```
myModule.directive('repeatClick', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function($element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr['repeatClick']);
      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('click', function(event) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(scope, {$event: event, $scope: scope});
          });
        });
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

That allows you to write your HTML like this:

```
<a href="" repeat-click="selectCar(car, $scope)">{{ car.name }}</a>
```

And your click handler:

```
$scope.selectCar = function(car, $repeatScope) {
  var newCar = ...;
  $repeatScope.car = newCar;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/dupiraju/2/edit

**EDIT**

My mistake, there's a much simpler way to do this. Your `selectCar()` method is going to be invoked on the `ng-repeat` scope, and you have access to it with `this` inside the function. So you can remove the `repeat-click` directive, and just change your `selectCar()` method to this:

```
$scope.selectCar = function(car) {
  var newCar = ...;
  this.car = newCar;
}
```