# How to get row data from table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am facing an issue. I have a table with one radio button. When the user selects any radio button and click on the submit button, I need to show the selected  rows details.

Html code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
            <th>Last Name</th> 
            <th>Unique Reference ID</th> 
            <th>Country</th> 
            <th>Branch</th> 
            <th>Card No</th> 
       </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr ng-repeat="d in Employees">
        <td><input type="radio"></td>
        <td>{{d.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{d.lname}}</td>
        <td>{{d.uniqueid}}</td>
        <td>{{d.country.name}}</td>
        <td> {{d.branch.name}}</td>
        <td>{{d.cardno}}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="Edit()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

controller code:

```
$scope.Edit=function()
{
    //need id of selected row ?
};
```

Comment: You put the checkbox and the edit function inside the ng-repeat, where you have access to individual employee items `d`, and also `$index` of the array.

Comment: @Mohammad I  can not  change  the  requirement.This has to be  in above  format only. Thanks for  you suggestion

Comment: please elaborate it is not clear. you are already showing the details in the table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="editData.employee = d">
```

And the controller:

```
$scope.editData = {};

$scope.Edit = function() {
  var id = $scope.editData.employee.id;
};
```

I just answered another question about how it affects your code that `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each list item, which is why you need the `editData` object for it to work. It could help you understand why you need it: [Angular replace data from ng-repeat item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398374/angular-replace-data-from-ng-repeat-item/22398995#22398995)

Comment: getting error $scope.employeeToEdit undefined..could you elaborate your code

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the `employeeToEdit` property was set on the ng-repeat scope and not the scope that your `Edit` method is on. I've updated my answer.

Comment: when i try to  print  id with  'alert' it is giving  'undefinded' value.

Comment: Try `console.log($scope.editData.employee)`. Looks like your id is called `uniqueid`, so you should probably use `.uniqueid` instead of `.id`.

Comment: sorry my  typing  mistake..Thanks .You  really save my  day.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `ng-model` and `ng-value` attributes in your radio input; see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D.

You'll also want to format your html with at least some semblance of sanity.